# How can I give HLS directive using Tcl script for all functions to make them combinational?

Tags: tcl, vivado-hls

I need to give directive to HLS using TCL script, but what i need to do for all functions to make combinational ? I can't add HLS pragma to the code.

Also, to get combinational output for any function, which HLS pragmas should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set directives in tcl directly without modifying your c/c++ source files. Simply run the commands in the vivado_hls tcl shell. For example type:

```
set_directive_array_map -mode horizontal "kernel1" stream
```

You can also put all directives in a tcl file and source that file once. Please consult the Command Reference in [UG902](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis) or [UG1399](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1399-vitis-hls/Vitis-HLS-Command-Reference) for possible commands and their effects.